# Cosmos DB internal error when fetching documents

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Using the Azure Cosmos DB Data Explorer shows me no values, even though I know there's data in it. When using my web app, I can see it inserts data. I can also verify this by querying `db.files.stats().count` from a local GUI. However at  any point in the UI where I try to read from the DB, it breaks -- seemingly the same issue as what I see in the GUIs I've tried to use.

Looking at the network tab in Chrome, I can see a failed request being sent to the `https://portal-prod-northeurope-mongo.portal-prod-northeurope.p.azurewebsites.net` endpoint whenever I try to refresh the result set.
The response it comes back with is

> Command find failed: Unknown server error occurred when processing this request..

I get the same error when I query the db with a local GUI so I assume it's not directly related to the Azure Portal.
I have tried to delete and recreate the collections but to no avail.
When I run all this locally on the Cosmos DB emulator, it works just fine.

Collections are defined as such:

```bsh
    az cosmosdb collection create --resource-group $resourceGroup `
                                  --name $dbService `
                                  --collection-name 'files' `
                                  --db-name $db `
                                  --partition-key-path '/p'

    az cosmosdb collection create --resource-group $resourceGroup `
                                  --name $dbService `
                                  --collection-name 'users' `
                                  --db-name $db

    az cosmosdb collection create --resource-group $resourceGroup `
                                  --name $dbService `
                                  --collection-name 'projects' `
                                  --db-name $db `
                                  --partition-key-path '/cb'
```

and an example object is the following:

```cs
internal class File
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "of")]
    public string OriginalFilename { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "if")]
    public string InternalFilename { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ua")]
    public DateTime UploadedAt { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "p")]
    public Guid ProjectId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "su")]
    public string StorageUri { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "t")]
    public byte Type { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
}
```

Comment: I have been asked by Cosmos DB support to put this here -- I've included identifiable information with the support request so they can look at the exact instance if necessary.

Comment: How are you inserting the data? This looks like a Mongo API account. Are you inserting the data through a Mongo client? Or are you using the Data Migration Tool or the Cosmos DB SDK?

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta Cosmos DB SDK. There's nothing special going on, the code is exactly this: https://gist.github.com/Vannevelj/a7fda9b9a7757d84342b4a36ef23c024#file-insert-cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments, the reason you are facing this issue is because you are using Cosmos DB SDK on a Mongo API account. Both the Portal and GUI are trying to consume the data through a Mongo client, and your data is being saved through a different API.

Cosmos DB SDK uses the **SQL API** to save documents. Mongo API accounts are meant to be used and consumed through Mongo Clients / Drivers.

If your application requires Mongo, then use Mongo Clients / Drivers to store the documents, don't use the Cosmos DB SDK.

If your application does not require Mongo (since you are using the Cosmos DB SDK it doesn't sound like it), **create a Core API(SQL)** account.

Comment: You're right, that seems to have done the trick. After clearing the collections and using the Mongo driver, I can see the data is formatted entirely differently and it's visible from the portal. It seems like I had a fundamental misunderstanding on how Cosmos DB relates to the models it supports. It would be helpful if there would be some sort of warning message about it in the portal but thanks nonetheless!

Answer (score 1):

Is there a data migration involved here...how is the data being created in Cosmos DB? Can you please provide a Json document example with all the system generated properties.
The Data Explorer issues tend to exist this migrated data where a predefined ID value is provided but doesn't match the format required by Cosmos DB.

Comment: I've removed the entire collection again and re-created data so it should all be in one format -- still have the issue. I've replaced all usages of `Guid` to a `string` to ensure that there's no funky behaviour with that going on either. This is the structure of an entry in the local data explorer which works fine. Going through the same steps on Azure, breaks. https://gist.github.com/Vannevelj/2a62bb4430c747af49f527dae2eb6ef2#file-file-json

Comment: I'm not sure if it's related to the `Guid` removal but I can see the data in my UI which means the code can retrieve it just fine. It only breaks when I attempt to view the data in Cosmos DB on Azure through a GUI.